# Simple random variable example

Tags: statistics, discrete-mathematics

I've been trying to solve this problem but I can't really understand how to.
The values in the set is just 12 and 0.1 so how should I reason?

**Question** :
X is a discrete random variable in Bin(12, 0.1).

Find the following probability
P(X = 4).

Comment: Can you tell us what Bin(12, 0.1) means? That might help _you_.

Comment: I have no idea, it is something that was not even specified in the exercise. I guess it is some set identifier, doubt it has any special implication though.

Comment: It is the only information you were given about $X$, so it is very important for the exercise. I'm quite sure that the notation was covered in your course or book. Looking up that notation is the key to this exercise.

Comment: Thanks Joonas, it turns out that it was some kind of binomial function!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here $X$ is a discrete random variable which follow Binomial distribution with the parameter values $12$ and $0.1$.

In general, the probability mass function of  random variable $X$ which follows $Bin(n,p)$, where $n$ is positive integer and $p\in[0,1]$ is given by 
$$P(X=x)=\frac{n!}{n!(n-x)!}(p)^x(1-p)^{n-x}$$ for $x=0,1,\ldots,n.$

In the given problem $n=12$, $p=0.1$ and $x=4$ so , putting all these values in the above expression we get, 
 $P(X=4)=\frac{12!}{12!(12-4)!}(0.1)^x(1-0.1)^{12-4}$

Now this simple calculation leads the answer.